# How do you fix "failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE" showing up in dmesg?

Tags: kernel, hard-drive

I just got a new Mushkin 60gb SSD, and it's now my primary drive in the ata1 spot. I've been getting these `failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE` errors which are preventing rebooting and shutdown.

Does anyone know what these could be caused by, or how to start troubleshooting?

**Note: I just installed Fedora Core 14 and I *did not* get this same issue at all. The SSD seems to work fine.**

I've tried these kernels in Ubuntu 10.04, with both giving the same error:

- 2.6.32-22-generic
- 2.6.31-17-generic

And this one in Fedora Core 14, which works fine:

- 2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686

There are some bug reports for Ubuntu and Fedora that mention this problem, and there doesn't seem to be a solution:

- [Fedora Bug 549981](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=549981)
- [Launchpad bug 445852](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libatasmart/+bug/445852?comments=all)
- [Launchpad bug 574462](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/574462)

Here is a link to my [entire `dmesg` from Ubuntu](http://pastie.org/1357556).

Here is a link to my [entire `dmesg` from Fedora Core 14](http://pastie.org/1534327)

And the relevant ata1.00 parts from the Ubuntu `dmesg` below:

```
[   59.804237] ata1: drained 256 bytes to clear DRQ.
[   59.804244] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   59.804249] ata1.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[   59.804254] ata1.00: cmd ec/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 pio 512 in
[   59.804256]          res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[   59.804258] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[   59.804264] ata1: hard resetting link
[   59.804266] ata1: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[   60.272036] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   60.352193] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   60.352204] ata1: EH complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling s.m.a.r.t. helps, but it still occurs when the device isn't cleanly closed during shutdown.
Tested with kernel 2.6.37-rc8-git1 ..

Scenarios that trigger this event are:

1. fsck (not cleanly unmounted)
2. flush cash ext (during shutdown)
3. identify device(triggered by smart
   or fsck during startup)

Comment: How do you disable SMART for a specific device, then? How else do you solve this problem?

Comment: Disable udev rules for smart in:/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules

Comment: You're correct on all of those three points. I disabled s.m.a.r.t. but the disk still stalls in those scenarios. Do you know how to fix this problem permanently? Windows doesn't have any problems at all...

Comment: I have a work around for the reboot, so now for me it is possible to reboot the machine without timeouts occurring:
Just change in /etc/init.d/reboot de shutdown command in:

 echo s >/proc/sysrq-trigger;

 echo u >/proc/sysrq-trigger;

 echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger;

Comment: I think some low level libata debugging is needed... Are there some connections to ocz with this problem?

Comment: How do you do the equivalent disabling of timeouts for the shutdown command?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find some answers in these two bug reports:

[Launchpad bug 445852](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libatasmart/+bug/445852?comments=all)

[Launchpad bug 574462](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/574462)

Comment: I disabled smart, and commented out the relevant lines in the mentioned files in /lib/udev/rules.d, which helped speed things up, but I still can't reboot and I still see the error in dmesg once during boot. I even dd'd my drive with to a bin file, then dd'd it with /dev/zero, then dd'd the bin file back to the drive, and that didn't change anything.

Comment: what is the definitive answer in those bugs? Disabling s.m.a.r.t. helps, but doesn't solve the problem.